# Where to find mails or mail addresses on a web server?

Tags: smtp

In a training lab I'm using for a computing security certification I just got root access to a SMTP server, and there are so much files to look for. I want to retrieve mails or mail addresses using or stored by this SMTP server.

Here are some directories that I found in the server and that could be interesting: **/usr/share/apps/kmail/;** **/usr/share/sendmail-cf; /etc/mail**

Do you have any other idea ?

Thanks

Comment: I would take a look in /var/mail/. But I will vote to close this question, as it is not about information security.

Comment: Also voted to close. But you also need to realise that 1) there are several components in a email system (MUA, MDA, MTA) 2) there are multiple vendors/products for each of these 3) they will all use different locations and file formats